# Databricks pyspark parallelize unzipping multiple files

Tags: pyspark, databricks, unzip

I'm trying to parallelize unzipping files stored in `s3` in `pyspark` on Databricks. Unzipping in a `for` loop works as so:

```
file_list = [(file.path, file.name) for file in dbutils.fs.ls(data_path) if os.path.basename(file.path).endswith(".zip")] # data_path is taken as a parameter
file_names = [ff[1] for ff in file_list]
for ff in file_list:
  dbutils.fs.cp(ff[0], "/FileStore/tmp/" + ff[1])
  cmd = 'unzip /dbfs/FileStore/tmp/' + ff[1]
  os.system(cmd)
  dbutils.fs.cp("file:/databricks/driver/" + ff[1], data_path)
  dbutils.fs.rm("file:/databricks/driver/" + ff[1])
```

I'm trying to parallelize the unzip part. So after copying the files to `"/FileStore/tmp/"` I'm running:

```
unzips = [file[1] for file in file_list]
def f(x):
  os.system('unzip /dbfs/FileStore/tmp/' + x)
sc.parallelize(unzips).foreach(f)
```

The job runs but the files are not unzipped anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add the `-d` option to put output onto DBFS, something like this:

```py
def f(x):
  os.system('unzip -o -d /dbfs/FileStore/tmp-output/ /dbfs/FileStore/tmp/' + x)
```

if necessary (for example, there is no directories inside archive), add more unique directory to each run, for example, append `x` to it.

Comment: Will try this. How do I see the documentation for `unzip`? I'm not sure where to go for that

Comment: Run %sh unzip without any parameter, or run man unzip on Linux or Mac

Comment: This works except for one issue. Sometimes not all of the files have unzipped when spark moves to the next cell on Databricks where I read the unzipped files. This causes it to fail with an error. Any idea how to avoid that?

Comment: you need to check output (executor logs via Spark UI) to see if there are any errors